# Shadows not influenced by normal map in BI

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

im new to Blender (**Blender Internal**). Hope anyone can help, i'm hurry cuz of a deadline!.

With a **plane** with a **normal map** aplied to it and it's material set to **Shadow Only** I'm triying to create an alpha bg video with particle with shadows projections over it (a dead body actually) to integrate later on AE.

The issue: **shadows are not bending** influenced by the normal map of the plane. (see red plane)

Solutions or performance improvements are very welcome!

[image: Shadows not influenced by normal map yet]

Comment: Are you using ray traced shadows?

Comment: on Render-> Shading-> ray tracing is activated. That's the way to turn them on?

Comment: On a lamp's properties enable ray shadow.

Comment: it's enabled already :/

Comment: Could you use a displacement instead?

Comment: Great @someonewithpc , that showed some improvement: with displace modifier applied, on texture view ,the shadow is bended by the form of the surface.

But

rendering using Material -> Shadows -> Shadows Only does not show any shadow proyected to the displaced plane. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Tweaking transparency settings I managed to get closer, now Shadows Only works. Thnx guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A normal map on a plane will fake the shading, but will not deform shadows projected on the plane.

[image]

Essentially the shadows are those of the underlaying plane.

[image]

To create real displacement: add a displacement modifier using a texture.
(Note you might need to subdivide your object and create more vertices to displace.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Beautifully explained!, the same @someonewithpc finally suggested. Thnx!